# Grab public member of abstract class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, subclass, abstract

I know that when I generate an abstract class and give it public members I can grab them from the child class. But I want to do exactly that, but on a general basis. For example:

```
public abstract class Tile {
    public int member = 0;
}
```

Now I create a lot of subclasses (at least 20). I have a list of mixed subclasses and I want to grab that public member.

```
ArrayList<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<>();
...
for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
    tiles.get(i).member++; // get and do something useful with member
}
```

Of course the list does (as far as I know) hold subclasses of Tile. I want to be able to grab the public member from the list of subclasses without having to know which subclass it is. Is there a way to accomplish this?

For clarity, this will not compile and the editor doesn't recognize the global member on the line `tiles.get(i).member`.

Comment: I am quite confused about your question, you already "gabbed" the Title instance in your loop and increment it by one.

Comment: What you're doing in your loop there works.

Comment: It doesn't work. Won't even compile. I have a list of type Tile (which is a parent class) but contains child classes. However, it won't let me grab or do anything with the public member, I have no idea why.

Comment: Why don't you flesh out your question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? As written, the code should work, so there must be some code that causes a problem in your "local" example.

Comment: I ran it, it works as you wrote it. Your problem is somewhere else. So no one can help you unless you add more code showing what you're doing.

Comment: Everyone, I am so sorry for wasting your time. While I was putting together the MCVE I ended up discovering the issue. I was confusing one list for another (two lists with the same name in related classes). I was able to fix the issue and change the names.

Comment: @TimothyEckstein You'll like [How a Rubber Duck Taught Me to Be a Better Programmer](http://blog.wsol.com/how-a-rubber-duck-taught-me-to-be-a-better-programmer) :-)